# Only index function is working inside a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a controller with two functions as below

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('registration/index');
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->load->view('registration/index');
    }
```

and following in the header.php file

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url("user/login")?>">Login</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url("user")?>">Register</a>
</li>
```

My problem is when I click on register button with `site_url('user')`, its working fine but when i click login button with `site_ur('user/login')` my css are not loaded. I have tried the same view for both the function. But later one is showing problem. 
Can anybody help me what configuration mistake I did. My file structure of view folder is:

```
- views
  -registration
     -index.php
     -index_script.php
  templates
     -header.php
     -footer.php
     -html_header.php
```

index.php has

```
    <?php $this->load->view("templates/html_header"); 
$data = array();
$data["additional_script"] = $this->load->view("registration/index_scripts", array(), true);
$this->load->view("templates/footer", $data);

?>
```

html_header.php contains

```
<!-- include angular js -->
<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<?php $this->load->view("templates/header")?>
```

header.php

Comment: show us where you have include css

Comment: @B.Desai I have all my bootstrap, jquery links inside application/views/templates/header.php and
application/views/templates/footer.php

Comment: Check your browser js console and see what path it's trying to load from.

Comment: share your code how you have included js and css.

Comment: @SS you need to show that part also where you have added css and js

Comment: It is set to load same view file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using is incorrect. You must add `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` to the script src.

For eg: `<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>`

Maybe this can work.

Comment: Have you removed index.php from URL in your Codeigniter project?? 
If not add <?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/remaining URL

Comment: Thank you that is my mistake

Comment: You are most welcome. Please accept my answer if it helped you.